# Change Background on Border using ColorAnimation

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I cannot seem to be able to animate the background color of a border using `ColorAnimation`.  I have looked at about 5 different various ways to do this off different SO answers and web pages but none seem to work.  What am I missing?

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#f0f0f0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Comment: I have tested it and it is working.

Comment: It insta crashes for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have set the `Border.Background` directly and not in `Style`. Then this will not work because of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing). You can't change a local value in a Style.

Comment: Set the Border Background with a Setter in Style.